# PCI Express not detecting graphic card

Tags: desktop-computer, pci

I have an old dell T1650. Everything was working fine until few days ago. I have a graphic card with dms-59 that split into 2 vga. for  many year, everything has just worked fine. Few days ago, it stopped working(When I try to connect graphic card, there is not output on the monitor), I tested the pci express card on another computer and my pci express is working fine. The build-in vga interface works fine, but since I use dual monitor, vga interface is not working fine for 2 computer. currently, I am stuck with on monitor and it borders me. I have tried to reset bio, but it did not help. I have try multiple other pci express card, but no respond. I thing the issu is the motheboard, but I am not sure. Since I don't have money to spend on new graphic card and computer?

Is there anyway to solve issues related to motherboad ?
Any advice will be very help full

Answer (score 1):

Your motherboard has two PCIe x16 slots. One is wired for PCIe 3.0 x16 and the other one is PCIe 2.0 x4 (but in x16 form factor). The former one is preferred for graphics cards, but you can use the other one to test if the graphics card works.

If it does, then the main slot is broken, but the other one will work fine (although the card may perform slightly worse).

If it doesn't work in either slot, but the same card works in a different PC, then it could be a software problem. I'd start with a clean install of Windows (make sure your backups are up to date first).

Your motherboard also has 2 DisplayPort outputs that you can use with active adapters to drive VGA displays. Or even better, if your monitors support digital connections (DVI-D, HDMI or DisplayPort), use these.